# How do I leave a message for another (local) user?

Tags: terminal, users, messaging

I know you can use `write` to send a message to a currently logged in user, but how do you leave a message for a user who is not logged in? The solution I have seen is modify the motd, but that will be displayed to all users. How can I leave a message for individual users to read when they login?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `mail` command to send a message to user `jdoe` like this:

```
mail -s "The subject goes here" jdoe
```

You will enter an interactive environment where you can type your message (mail body). Type `Control-D` in the beginning of a line to end the message and send it (you will be asked for an optional CC recipient - just hit enter if you don't want one).

You can also do:

```
mail -s "The subject goes here" jdoe < textfile
```

or

```
echo "John, please don't forget our meeting" | mail -s "Reminder" jdoe
```

The next time jdoe logs in, he will receive a notification like "You have new mail" and he must type `mail` to read it (perhaps this is a drawback if the user doesn't know he must do this).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Now is there a way to show how many new messages there are without opening `mail`? I'm reading the man page and I don't see a way to do that. I also can't make a bash script that pushes 'q' for me as far as I know.

Comment: I noticed that when I login, it says 'You have mail' so that is already solved. But in case anyone is wondering, you can use a script like `echo "q" | mail` to see how many messages you have.

Comment: Note that the mentioned notification is issued by the shell and can be turned off. Supposing you use Bash, see `MAIL`, `MAILCHECK` and `MAILPATH` in the man to know what you can expect.

Comment: You can also run biff to monitor the mailbox.

Comment: this didn't work. I sent a mail to a local user and logged in to that user but didn't receive any mail.

Comment: I have configured `postfix` and `dovecot` on my server with pam authentication. do they interfere with local mail system?

Answer (score -5):

Try wall, http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall Maybe that will do the trick?

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of what he wants. He wants a command that leaves a message for a specific, logged out user; wall shows a message to all users currently logged in