# Can't send local mail message between users on linux

Tags: arch-linux, email, users, postfix, mailx

In https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21336/99621 it says that if you do

```
echo 'body' | mail -s 'subject' myuser
```

It will send a mail message to the `myuser` linux account on the local system that this user can check with the `mail` command. I tried sending mail to my own user account by running that command and it executes without any problems (no output in terminal and 0 exit code).

But when I type `mail` to check for mail, it says `No mail for myuser`.

If I replace the above mail sending command with one that doesn't exist, such as `notexistinguser`, the command still executes without any problems.

How can I send mail to a local Linux user account and check it? (I'm on a pretty minimal installation Archlinux.) I've also installed Postfix which is up and running with the default configuration, thought it might have interfered so I stopped it but still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

For `mail` to work as expected it requires a mail transfer agent (MTA), such as `Sendmail`, or `Postfix`. A minimal installation of Arch Linux includes neither.

You're on the right track installing `Postfix`. The Arch wiki has a guide for configuring `Postfix` specifically for local mail delivery here: [Postfix - Local mail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Postfix#Local_mail).

After modifying your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` configuration file with the changes suggested in the wiki article, you'll want to start the `Postfix` daemon with the following command:

```
$ systemctl start postfix
```

To permanently enable local mail delivery thereafter:

```
$ systemctl enable postfix
```